# Return child class in parent method C#

Tags: c#, oop

I have parent class:

```
public abstract class ParentClass
{
     public ParentClass ParentMethod() { ... }
}
```

Also I have two childs:

```
public class ChildA : ParentClass
{
    public ChildA ChildAMethod1()
    {
        ... 
        return this; 
    }

    public ChildA ChildAMethod2()
    {
        ... 
        return this; 
    }
}

public class ChildB : ParentClass
{
     public ChildB ChildBMethod() { ... 
            return this; }
}
```

In this case I have possibility to write like this:

```
new ChildA().ChildAMethod1().ChildAMethod2();
```

But how to implement possibility to write like this:

```
new ChildA().ParentMethod().ChildAMethod1().ChildAMethod2();

new ChildB().ParentMethod().ChildBMethod1();
```

Is there any other patterns to such possibility?

Comment: Does ParentMethod also return this or can it be any object of ParentClass type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make ParentMethod generic

```
public abstract class ParentClass
{
    public T ParentMethod<T>() where T:ParentClass
    {
        return (T)this; 
    }
}
```

then call it like

```
new ChildA().ParentMethod<ChildA>().ChildAMethod1().ChildAMethod2();
new ChildB().ParentMethod<ChildB>().ChildBMethod1();
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm looking for. I've little bit modified it. Just made
public abstract class ParentClass<T> 

and then 
public class ChildA : ParentClass<ChildA>
public class ChildB : ParentClass<ChildB>

and returns T in child methods.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What is the connection between parent and child class if methods of the child are not inherited from parent?

Since classes are already decoupled, you can emphasize that decoupling via an interface:

```
public interface INext
{
    INext ChildAMethod1();
    INext ChildAMethod2();
}

public abstract class ParentClass
{
    public INext ParentMethod()
    {
        ...
        return new ChildA(...);
    }
}

public class ChildA : ParentClass, INext
{
    public INext ChildAMethod1()
    {
        ... 
        return this; 
    }

    public INext ChildAMethod2() 
    {
        ... 
        return this; 
    }
}
```